# Node Stub a method that returns an object

Tags: node.js, sinon, proxyquire

I have a module that has some properties. I am using it as below

```
Var propmodule = require('me-props');
var prop = new propmodule('server');
prop.get('min); //returns 3
prop.get('max') //returns 10
```

I have to mock this for testing. Did the below code using proxyquire and sinon

```
var spro = proxyquire('../lib/add.js',{
'me-props' : sinon.stub.returns({
    get : sinon.stub.returns({
       min :'3',
       max : '10
)}
)}
})
```

The above code works. But while testing, the get method call returns an object.
get(min) returns an object.
var a = prop.get() and then a('min') returns 3.
But prop.get('min') returns an object.

How can i modify the stub to return the value for the get call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to predicate the `returns` with a `withArgs` so it will match the function arguments (`min` and `max`) and return a appropriate value:

```
var stub = sinon.stub();
stub.withArgs('min').returns('3');
stub.withArgs('max').returns('10');
stub.throws('InvalidArgument'); // Throw an exception when an invalid argument is used.

var spro = proxyquire('../lib/add.js', { 'me-props' : { get : stub } });
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. But dont i need a "get" stub as well in the above code?

Comment: @ShabinHashim not ignorance, just a silly mistake on my part! Edited my answer =D

Comment: Required a slight modification :
{'me-props' : sinon.stub().returns({ get : stub})

Thanks.