# SINON unittesting stub constructor

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, stub

I'm trying to stub a constructor in node but I really can't.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847398/node-stub-a-method-that-returns-an-object) , that is quite similiar to what I need to do but I have an error that I could not solve.

```
//file.js
var foo = require('foo-client')
function toTest () {
     var bar = foo()
    returns config = bar.foo2(a,b)  // returns a Promise
}
```

what I am trying to do in the test file is

```
//file-sepc.js
var stub = sinon.stub()
stub.returns(Promise.resolve('config'))// config it's just an example

    var file = proxyquire('./file.js', {
        'foo-client':{foo2: stub}
    })
file.toTest()
.then((result) => {
     console.log(result)
     done()
})
```

supposing the node syntax is correct, I am getting this output:

```
 TypeError: foo is not a function
```

Can anyone help me telling me where is my error or another way to mock/stub this things?

### Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried running your code but it looks like foo-client should be a function rather than an object in order for the var bar = foo() not to throw an error you are seeing. Try the following:

```
var file = proxyquire('./file.js', {'foo-client': sinon.stub.returns({ foo2: stub }) })
```

Comment: Not working again. Now the error is... 
`TypeError: bar.foo2 is not a function`